# C# error trying to get dot product

Tags: c#, vector

I am currently using openGL to create a 3d animation which has collisions. I have used dot to get the dot product multiple times which have all been working fine, however for some reason this is causing an error:

```
Vector3 normalise = (line2 - line1).Normalized();
        Vector3 hyp = line2 - line1;
        Vector3 dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(normalise, hyp);  //this is where there is an error
```

The error it is throwing is: "Cannot explicitly convert type 'float' to 'OpenTK.Vector3'.

However I haven't used any floats and I have used the same as I have in other parts of the program.

Thanks
Lucy

Comment: From my maths dot products return a scalar, not a vector. Check your return type and what variable you are sticking it in...

Comment: Also when reporting errors always make it clear what line is throwing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at the method signature we see it is:

```
public static float Dot(Vector3 left, Vector3 right)
```

As we can see it takes two `Vector3` objects as parameters (which you are doing) and returns a `float`. However, you are trying to assign this to `Vector3 dotProduct` which is the wrong type. The compiler is thus having to try to convert a `float` to a `Vector3` to assign it to `dotProduct` which is generating the error you see.

To fix this simply change to:

```
float dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(normalise, hyp);
```

Comment: Thank you thats perfect!